# Is redis limiting the number of clients to 65K?

Tags: linux, architecture, linux-kernel, redis, nonblocking

I am using Redis 2.4.6 Stable.
I have increased the number of redis file descriptors in file ae.h to over 200K:

`#define AE_SETSIZE (1024*200)`

But when running it I am reaching a limit of 65534.

I am running redis on ec2 on a RedHat instance: 2.6.32-220.2.1.el6.x86_64
and I am running redis with a **ulimit -n 200000**

I have set up tests with multiple ec2 nodes that try to push the concurrent connections to over 150K, but it will not beyond 65K.

Any ideas of what can I be missing? Maybe a kernel limitation? bug in redis?

This is a dump of INFO on the redis server:

```
used_cpu_sys_children:0.00
used_cpu_user_children:0.00
**connected_clients:65534**
connected_slaves:0
client_longest_output_list:0
client_biggest_input_buf:0
blocked_clients:0
used_memory:572810560
used_memory_human:546.27M
used_memory_rss:305123328
used_memory_peak:572810528
used_memory_peak_human:546.27M
mem_fragmentation_ratio:0.53
```

Comment: Hi David, does dmesg or anything in /var/log indicate anything once you hit the 65k limit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you running afoul of network port limitations? Depending on how the clients are closing the connections you could simply be running out of ports, as they will get stuck in the TIME_WAIT state.

If that is the case, one way to get around it is to bind multiple internal IP's to the server and distribute accordingly. Or alternately, if you can modify the client you're using, making sure that it closes the connection in such a way that it takes on the burden of TIME_WAIT.

Comment: that might be. I will have a look at that. Unfortunately I need my clients to keep those connections open.

Comment: fixed. It was an OS network related parameter (/proc/sys/net/nf_conntrack_max). Redis can now process mostly anything I throw at it.

Comment: +1 @DavidCostaFaidella you should accept this answer since it fixed your problem